# Find exponential decay equation for tiger population model

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I've forgotten how to do it first it starts..

In 1900, there were 100,000 wild tigers worldwide; in 2010 the number was 3200.

(a) Assuming that the tiger population has decreased exponentially, find a formula for f(t) , the number of wild tigers t years since 1900.

(b) Between 2000 and 2010, the number of wild tigers decreased by 40% . Is this percentage larger or smaller than the decrease in the tiger population predicted by your answer to part (a)?

For (a) I  assumed

```
f(t) = 100'000 *N^t 
f(110) = 100'000 *N^110 = 3200
                      N = (32/1000)^(1/110)    
                        = 0.9691....
```

Therefore...

```
f(t) = 100'000*0.9691^t
```

Which I know is wrong.

Comment: So for a i got f(t) = 100'000 * 0.97^t

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). The title should be descriptive. Words like "please" and "help" do not belong in titles; they are clutter. Proper capitalization is not optional. As for the math: how do you know the answer to (a) is wrong? What you did makes sense. For part (b) I would plug in $t=100$ to find the prediction for 2000, and then find the percentage decrease for 2000-2010 based on that prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula $$100000*0.9691^t$$ is actually an increasing function.

Try $$f(t)=100000\times N^{-t}$$
Spoiler:Answer:

> $$f(t)=100000\times(1.0318)^{-t}$$

---

From the formula get no. of tigers in 2000 and 2010, then find decrease percent.

Comment: Thanks for b i went since (1.0318)^-10 < 0.4 then the second function is significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

$100000(0.9691)^t \; \text{is} \;\underline{\textbf{not}}\; \text{an increasing function.}$

$y=b^t \; \text{is an increasing function when }b>1, \; \textrm{but when }0<b<1,\; y=b^t \;\textrm{is a decreasing function} .$

$ \text{Suppose you let t = the number of }\; \underline{\text{decades}}\;\text{ since 1900.  So here t = 11 decades.}$

$ \text {Then}\;\; f(11) = 3200=100000*N^{11}  $

$ \text {Thus}\;\; N=\sqrt[11]{\frac{32}{1000}}=\sqrt[11]{0.032}\approx0.7313151   $

$ \text {So the function is}\;\; f(t) = 100000(0.7313151)^{t} ,\; \text{where }t\;  \text{is measured in} \;\underline{\textbf {decades}}\;\text{after 1900.} $

$\text{In part (b) when it says "the number of wild tigers decreased by 40%", it means }$
$\displaystyle f(11)=f(10)-40\%*f(10)=f(10)-0.4*f(10)= f(10)(1-0.4)=0.6*f(10) $

$\displaystyle \text{In general, percent increase/decrease is defined as} \;\;\frac{\text{original number}\; \pm \; \text{new number}}{\text{original number}} $

$\text{Because}\;f(10)\;\text{comes before}\;f(11) ,\; \text{percent decrease means }$

$\displaystyle\frac{f(10)-f(11)}{f(10)}=\frac{f(10)}{f(10)}-\frac{f(11)}{f(10)}=1-N=1-\sqrt[11]{0.032}\approx1-0.7313151=.2686849$
$$ \approx 27\%$$

$\text{Or in your case,}$

$\displaystyle\frac{f(100)-f(110)}{f(100)}=\frac{f(100)}{f(100)}-\frac{f(110)}{f(100)}=1-N^{110-100}=1-N^{10}=1-\left(\;\sqrt[110]{0.032}\;\right)^{10}$
$$\approx1-0.7313151=.2686849 \approx 27\%$$

$\text{Therefore between 2000 to 2010, the number of wild tigers decreased by  approximately 27%.}$